# Коммиты в ветках на github

Tags: git, github

У меня есть локальный репозиторий git. Я создал 1 доп ветку(назовем ее branch1), и сделал в нее 1 коммит. Сейчас локально log показывает что в ветке мастер у меня 10 коммитов, в ветке branch1 11 коммитов.     Теперь мне нужно было залить проект на github.
Сначала создал новый github реп, куда автоматом закомиттился readme. 
Заливаю локальный на github. Попытался залить через push origin master, но git начал ругаться. В git'e я профан, да и времени разбираться не было, так что попробовал залить через push origin branch1. И все залилось.
Однако теперь онлайн реп показывает, что в ветке master только 1 коммин(тот что с readme), a в branch1 11 коммитов(как и локально). 
Вопрос, как сделать чтоб master включал в себя 10 первых локальных коммитов.

Comment: @gcoder, у вас в результате появилось две совсем разных ветки master. Возможно, их можно слить через доп. ветки и всякие `--force`, либо удалить и воссоздать ветку в одной из реп, но самым безгеморным решением будет создать репу заново.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вообщем снес readme, сделал poll, ветки master автоматом смержились и запушил master обратно

Answer (score 2):

Не включать туда README при создании репозитория.

Comment: т.е сносить репозиторий и создавать заново?